# Using Symfony, sfDoctrineGuardPlugin plugin, How can i customise sf_content? Using partials?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, partial, sfdoctrineguard

I am using symfony 1.4.8 with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin for my backend.

My question is how can i customise sfDoctrineGuardPlugin's default content? For example, how can i do something on the page between filter and table (on the left hand site)? Or, how can i customize table (http://goo.gl/ZmRey)?

I cannot find any solution for using partials on backend. Is there any way to use partials/components/slots on backend?

I hope you understand my question and tell me a way.

Thanks for your answer(s), 
Erman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials, components and slots are no different on the back-end to the front-end - your "backend" is just another Symfony application.  From the screenshot you gave, it looks like you're looking to customise the admin generator theme.

The quickest way to get started with this is to look in your `cache/appname/` folder and see the automatically-generated modules here, with all the template files, partial files and so on.  You can then create an empty module in your application, and override select parts of the theme with whatever you want to change.  See [this part](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12#chapter_12_templates_customization) of the Symfony docs for a full list of partials etc, and how to go about overriding them in more detail.

In the specific case of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin-module pages, these can be overrided in the same way as normal modules - simply create eg an sfGuardAuth module and override the selected parts of the module you want to.

If you want to go further and create your own admin generator theme, this is a bit more advanced.  Here I will shamelessly promote a [blog post](http://www.whiteoctober.co.uk/blog/2010/03/23/symfony-admin-generator-theming/) I wrote last year ;-) John Cleveley's [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jcleveley/working-with-the-admin-generator) also provides some great tips.

Comment: thank you very much richsage. i got it. i am looking at them now.